# Original papers on $\aleph_0$-categorical theory

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

I'd like to find original papers by Ryll-Nardzewski and Svenonius on $\aleph_0$-categorical theory.

1. Ryll-Nardzewski. "On the categoricity in power $\aleph_0$", Bulletin of Academy of Polish science mathematic 7, 545-548, 1959.
2. Svenonius. "$\aleph_0$-categoricity in first-order predicate calculus", Theoria (Lund) 25, 82-94, 1959a.
3. (Possibly) Svenonius. "A theorem on permutations in models", Theoria (Lund) 25, 173-178, 1959b.

On the webpage of [Bulletin Polish Acad. Sci. Math](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/bulletin-polish-acad-sci-math), there are only issues after 2004. How do I get issues of older years? Is there a free version of 2 (and 3)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you looking for the original papers?

Comment: I found that the proof of it in "Model Theory" by Chang and Keisler is not clear enough. So I decide to read the original papers by Ryll-Nardzewski and Svenonius

Comment: The proof of what? (Regardless, I'd strongly recommend checking additional contemporary texts before going back to the original papers - exposition generally improved over time.)

Comment: I do not think so. I find that proofs in old texts such as Chang and Keisle's model theory are the best to my knowledge, better than current texts whose proofs are often vague and unsatisfactory.  From past experience, Polish works in set and logic theory are often very clear.

Comment: What specific result are you looking for a proof of?

Comment: A $ℵ_0$-categorical theory only has finitely many types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Theoria* is fully online it seems; Svenonius' papers can be found [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1755-2567.1959.tb00294.x) and [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1755-2567.1959.tb00301.x) respectively. These are behind paywalls, however, and I don't think they are legally freely accessible online. A library is probably your best bet (and for the Ryll-Nardzewski as well).